# Can AlexNet "see" small sub-images at edges of image?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am using the standard AlexNet model with image data size 3*224*224. I artificially construct these images, which consists of numerous sub-images.

I am trying to recognize small, simple sub-images (100*2) that might be at side or corner of 224*224 space.

Is AlexNet likely to handle this well? Or should sub-image really take-up most of the 224*224?

Comment: It is not likely to handle that well, unless, perhaps, you have a corpus of data that you can train AlexNet on that has such images.  You might be able to create such a dataset artificially.  In any case, you probably want something like [yolo](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) which is specifically designed to detect objects in subimages.

Comment: OK thank you. On a quick read - I don't see a comparison to AlexNet. Is there any data on their relative effectiveness?

Comment: They do different things.  So, no.  AlexNet isn't made for subimage search.  YOLO isn't made for full image classification.  However, YOLO is trained on the COCO database, which is smaller, and with fewer classes.  Also, subimage search is a harder problem. So, I woudn't expect it to perform as well at subimage search as state-of-the-art full-image classification models are at full-image classification.  However, if you're doing subimage search, then whatever results are reported for AlexNet are irrelevant.  You could test AlexNet on [COCO](http://cocodataset.org/#home) and see what it finds.

Comment: Also, note that AlexNet is [old news at this point](https://medium.com/coinmonks/paper-review-of-vggnet-1st-runner-up-of-ilsvlc-2014-image-classification-d02355543a11) There are probably even newer models, now, but I'm a bit behind in my reading.  I've used VGG net before, and their stuff is pretty accessible.

Comment: So, how are you suggesting I use YOLO for my project? I have total control of the construction of the training images.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your project, so I have no idea.  Alls I knows is that if you want to do subimage search and classification, you should use a model designed for that thing.  There are [other options](https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-r-cnn-object-detection-implemented-by-keras-for-custom-data-from-googles-open-images-125f62b9141a).  The terms you probably want to google are "attention" and "region of interest"/"roi" and "object detection", along with "CNN" or some other generic machine-learningy terms.

Comment: Last I checked, YOLO was a good option.  Unfortunately, he wrote all of his ML libraries from scratch in C++ and doesn't keep up with them all that well.  So tying your own stuff into YOLO can be quite a hassle.  This is the extent of my knowledge on the subject.  Best of luck.  :)

Comment: @Scott One last thing. I was surprised to get a speedy response from you on Stackoverflow - which is for coding really. Are there any other forums for this sort of thing? DataScience seems to lack many contributors

Comment: I'm not sure.  In my experience, posts tagged with "machine-learning" get a *lot* of leeway in terms of the ordinary SO posting rules.  I routinely see stuff like "why does my model have poor accuracy?", which is not very StackOverflow-y if you ask me.  Unfortunately, the ML community just isn't as big as, say, the javascript community, and the questions are never as cut-and-dry, so it can be hard to get help.  If you find any forums that are helpful, I would love to hear about them.

Comment: Occasionally you can get good answers to ML type stuff on [stats stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neural-networks).  They may be in more of a position to answer the "do you expect this to have good accuracy" type questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing, I have found that AlexNet does not see very small objects well within image. I suspect that this is due to stride size.